# Implementar opção favoritos num servidor

Tags: regra-de-negócio

Estou tentando implementar a opção do usuário favoritar um item de uma lista e estou em dúvida de qual melhor forma fazer isso. O cenário é o seguinte, todos os usuários tem acesso a mesma lista de itens que é puxada do servidor sempre que abre o app. Os dados do usuário serão salvos no servidor, quero saber como fazer isso sem ter que criar uma cópia de toda a lista de itens para cada usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Não há uma forma de gerar um relacionamento entre duas entidades sem gerar um novo registro, no caso como é N p/ N, sempre haverá um dado a ser replicado, então a sua decisão deverá ser focada em escolher se quer um relacionamento e lidar com as integridade dos dados ou se vai fazer uma cópia do dado não tendo que se preocupar com a origem dela.